# excel - vba prevent custom style indent removal

Tags: excel, vba

My Excel table(List Object) has  a column with many level indent. In my vba sub I apply a custom style on that column and all indent are removed. How can I prevent indent level change.

Answer (score 0):

Here the fix I have done in my vba custom stlye " .IncludeAlignment = False"

```
 With ActiveWorkbook.Styles("D Input")
      .IncludeNumber = True
      .IncludeFont = True
      .IncludeAlignment = False  'Was thrue
      .IncludeBorder = True
      .IncludePatterns = True
      .IncludeProtection = True
    End With
```

.
.
.
.